# How to get ID of a map task in Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is there a way to get ID of a map task in Spark? For example if each map task calls a user defined function, can I get the ID of that map task from whithin that user defined function?

Answer (score 33):

I am not sure what you mean by ID of map task but you can access task information using `TaskContext`:

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext

sc.parallelize(Seq[Int](), 4).mapPartitions(_ => {
    val ctx = TaskContext.get
    val stageId = ctx.stageId
    val partId = ctx.partitionId
    val hostname = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
    Iterator(s"Stage: $stageId, Partition: $partId, Host: $hostname")
}).collect.foreach(println)
```

A similar functionality has been added to PySpark in Spark 2.2.0 ([SPARK-18576](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18576)):

```py
from pyspark import TaskContext
import socket

def task_info(*_):
    ctx = TaskContext()
    return ["Stage: {0}, Partition: {1}, Host: {2}".format(
        ctx.stageId(), ctx.partitionId(), socket.gethostname())]

for x in sc.parallelize([], 4).mapPartitions(task_info).collect():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`TaskContext.taskAttemptId`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/TaskContext.html#taskAttemptId--) is what you want. You can get the current task's context within a function via [`TaskContext.get`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/TaskContext.html#get--).