# Spark: How to separate data processing to point to different Mongodb instances that run in memory on RamFS/TmpFS partitions?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I have different instances of MongoDB on the same machine, and all of these are pointing to partitions that are created in memory with Linux, in a sort of:

```
mount -t ramfs -o size=8000M ramfs /mongo/ramdata<n>/
```

with this configuration for each `<n>` (e.g.: 1) MongoDB instance:

```
dbpath=/mongo/ramdata1/
nojournal = true
smallFiles = true
noprealloc = true
```

Those instances have exactly the same data, and I am just using purely MongoDB-Java driver to geo-query those data which are meant to be read-only (no MongoDB-hadoop or Stratio or whatsover).

So at some point I would like that my Spark process to finish with something like:

```
...foreach(query_a_specific-mongo_instance_for_a_specific_port)
```

as the MongoDB instances will run at the same address but different ports.

Given that I don't want to create a MongoDB replica set with one or more Mongo-conf instances, is it possible "partition" the process-flow with Spark in a way that, for example, every single "core/partition" point to a specific Mongoldb port?

For example if I have 100 cores, the first "core" will point to `mongo-address:30001`, and the 100th core will point to `mongo-address:30100`?

Comment: If these run on the same machine and use the same data why run multiple instances at all?

Comment: it seems mongo is locking the queries over a specific limit. However it is a temporary configuration, once is locally fixed will be "distributed".

Comment: Maybe I am simplifying things a bit but why not simply use round robin over partitions?

Comment: How? I was thinking doing some sort of partition like "if one parameter is in this range of values use this instance, otherwise another".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` with a small helper:

```
val mongos: Vector[String] = ??? // Vector("mongodb://mongo-address:30001", ...)

def getClient(mongos: Seq[String])(i: Integer): MongoClient = {
  MongoClient(mongos(i % mongos.size))
}

rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, iter) => {
  val client = getClient(mongos)(i)
  iter.map(someFunctionsWhichIsUsingTheClient)
})
```

For other actions or transformations you can get partition / host info using `TaskContext`. See [How to get ID of a map task in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31631791/1560062)