# Spark: How to debug/log a task at specific index

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have one process that stucks at the same point. The information that I know is the Task's index at the Details pages (referring to the Dashboard UI).

How can I debug/log exactly that task at specific index?

Based on then answer in:

[How to get ID of a map task in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631791/how-to-get-id-of-a-map-task-in-spark)

I can see how to get task info. But what are the IDs in the UI dashboard referred to in that object?

is ID = org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskInfo.id and Index = org.apache.spark.schedulerTaskInfo.partionId ?

Answer (score 2):

The IDs in the dashboard refers to partitions in spark. Whenever a job is launched, your input data is partitioned and depending on the number of partitions, you'll have them mapped to task IDs.

It's not a trivial task to debug spark jobs as they're map reduce tasks of your data done by your algorithm. It's fairly easy though, to add logs to debug your job after the fact. The logs would have to be collected on the workers, or in each of the executor's working directory.