# spark foreachPartition, how to get an index of each partition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

spark `foreachPartition`, how to get an index of the partition (or sequence number, or something to identify the partition)?

```
val docs: RDD[String] = ...

println("num partitions: " + docs.getNumPartitions)

docs.foreachPartition((it: Iterator[String]) => {
  println("partition index: " + ???)
  it.foreach(...)
})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `TaskContext` ([How to get ID of a map task in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31631791/8371915)):

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext

rdd.foreachPartition((it: Iterator[String]) => {
  println(TaskContext.getPartitionId)
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly identical, but you can use [`RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@mapPartitionsWithIndex[U](f:(Int,Iterator[T])=%3EIterator[U],preservesPartitioning:Boolean)(implicitevidence$9:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) and return an `Iterator[Unit]` as a result:

```
val rdd: RDD[Unit] = docs.mapPartitionsWithIndex { case (idx, it) => 
  println("partition index: " + ???)
  it.foreach(...)
}
```

But then you have to remember to materialize the `RDD`

An alternative would be to use `mapPartitionsWithIndex` to do logic related to transforming the data, and then using `foreachRDD` just to send the data externally.