# Fetch NodeID In Spark At Runtime

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Is there anyway to get the **Node ID** in a cluster at runtime so that We can use that node ID to concatenate with any column and Process it?

I am trying to create unique identifier which will consist of `<timeStamp> + <Node ID>+ <any col data>.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ID of a map task in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631791/how-to-get-id-of-a-map-task-in-spark)

Comment: Requirement is to get the Node ID only. I think getting task ID is the granular level ID for the NODE where one node can have multiple Task. Any help is really appreciated .