# How to know which partition is currently running while using foreachPartition() function in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a requirement to save partitions to the text file with different names for each partition.
But while running below code snippet only one file is saving by overwriting the previous partition.

```
def chunks(iterator):
    chunks.counter += 1
    l = (list(iterator))
    df = pd.DataFrame(l,index=None)
    df.to_csv(parent_path+"C"+str(chunks.counter+1)+".txt", header=None, index=None, sep=' ')

chunks.counter=0
sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5,6],num_partions).foreachPartition(chunks)
```

Is there any way that I can know which partition is currently running in pySpark?

Comment: Do we really need PySpark here?

Comment: I shared code with a sample list of 6 elements. But in actual there are many.

Answer (score 0):

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    # Yield successive n-sized chunks from the lst...
    for i in (range(0, len(lst), n)):
        yield i, lst[i:i + n]

for (index, values) in chunks(range(0, 1e5), 1e3): # change this to int's as per your need otherwise it will give float error or will write range obj itself..
    with open(f"{parent_path}_C_{index}.txt", "w") as output:
        output.write(str(values)) # converting to str
```

And you can even wrap this into joblib easily ;) We don't need PySpark as such in my opinion..

Comment: Thanks, Aditya for your code.

I did the chucking in native python in 1st and now am trying to do the same using pyspark.

here in this line
sc.parallelize(patient_ids,num_partions).foreachPartition(chunk_patients)

foreachPartition() is taking single partition at one run and processing the above function
here am unable to save different chunks with different names.

I tried the counter thing in another way also, but iterator resetting the counter value every time.

Comment: I am not a native PySpark user but the below seems promising, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631791/how-to-get-id-of-a-map-task-in-spark

Comment: Thank You, Aditya.
with minimal changes, it worked.  :}