# What does TID mean in the spark log?

Tags: performance, apache-spark

Here is an example from one of my spark logs:

```
21/03/31 19:51:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 362467.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 362470, ip-10-252-47-180, executor 223, partition 362467, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7453 bytes)
21/03/31 19:51:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 362468.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 362471, ip-10-252-46-204, executor 127, partition 362468, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7453 bytes)
21/03/31 19:51:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 361874.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 361877) in 13503 ms on ip-10-252-46-204 (executor 127) (361652/1372624)
21/03/31 19:51:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 362469.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 362472, ip-10-252-46-14, executor 282, partition 362469, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7453 bytes)
21/03/31 19:51:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 361873.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 361876) in 13504 ms on ip-10-252-47-180 (executor 223) (361653/1372624)
21/03/31 19:51:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 361872.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 361875) in 13505 ms on ip-10-252-46-14 (executor 282) (361654/1372624)
21/03/31 19:51:33 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 362470.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 362473, ip-10-252-44-7, executor 421, partition 362470, PROCESS_LOCAL, 7453 bytes)
```

- What does TID mean?

Also:

- Does `361654/1372624` mean that task 361,654 out of 1,372,624 tasks has run?

Also, I saw this wacky message:

```
21/03/31 19:06:23 INFO ExecutorAllocationManager: Requesting 161268 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 685555)
```

How can it request 161,268 executors? I'm running on 12 machines with 96 cores, using the default of 1 core/executor. SO I've only got 1152 cores to play around with.

Comment: maybe taskattemptID: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631791/how-to-get-id-of-a-map-task-in-spark

Answer (score 1):

about spark ,I think it should be task ID

Comment: That makes sense, but why so many executors?